# Why does JavaScript injected in a iframe use the parent window as its global scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

With an Ajax call I get a "blob" of content that I need to inject in an iframe. I've no control over the content... it might be only HTML or HTML + JavaScript.

As a "template" I use an empty html file as my iframe src. Upon the "load" event of the iframe, I push the blob into its body. It mostly works (using jQuery):

`$iframe.contents().find('body').html(my blob);`

What happens is that the "window" object of the JS injected with this system is the `window.top`, the parent window. Why?

I think the problem might be related on how jQuery html() works, but I can't figure out a cross browser way to do the same operation w/o using jQuery.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: this is the very minimal case:

```
<iframe id="z" src="scene.html"></iframe>

<script>

var xxx = 13;

$("#z").load(function() {

  var c = "<scri" + "pt>console.log(xxx)</scr" + "ipt>";

  $(this).contents().find('body').append(c);

})

</script>
```

In the console we read "13" (and I do not access the javascript objects that are already present in scene.html).

Comment: I think something else is wrong, couse I have done something similar and don't recognize the problem. How do you inject the new Javascript into the iframe? Is it just by passing the "my blob" that contain a <script> tag?

Comment: Simon, yes exactly. Tested also with a simpler ```$iframe.contents().find('body').append(myblob);``` The js is being executed, but in the "wrong" scope.

Comment: And if you inspect the DOM its correct? Do you get same result if you using native javascript: document.getElementById("iframe").innerHTML = myBlob. Could you provide a demo?

Comment: I added an example. innerHTML does not "execute" JS so it's useless...

Comment: Isn't this works as expected? (Based on your example) http://jsfiddle.net/EWGzJ/

Comment: try declaring `$('#z').contents().find('body').append(c);` to further debug this, as anonymous functions have the window as their owner.

Comment: Simon, interesting. The jsfiddle works as expected. A page with the same content does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `scene.html`:

```
function myAppendFunc(html) {
    $('body').append(html);
}
```

Then call it from outside:

```
$("#z").load(function() {
    var c = "<scri" + "pt>console.log(xxx)</scr" + "ipt>";
    this.contentWindow.myAppendFunc(c);
})
```

That should work.

Comment: Nope (and this is another "wtf!?" because this approach is clever and "bullet proof"). I added a console.log(window.xxx); in myAppendFunc and it is "undefined". The console.log() keep printing "13".

Comment: What browser are you using? I did it on chrome and it worked fine.

Comment: Solved using ```this.contentWindow.document.write(html);``` instead of relying on jQuery (edit: no, I did not). I'm using Chrome or FF on Ubuntu...

Comment: Yes, it works! The reason it was not working, is that I was re-using the jQuery of the parent, instead of using one in the iframe. The $ was then still working on the parent window. I wonder now if there is a way to not load another copy of jQuery just to use the $append.

Comment: You don't have to worry about that - if your outer page needs jQuery and your inner as well, the browser is clever enough to use the cached version on the second jQuery request...